# How to use textarea resize icon in comments on Galaxy S5?

Tags: bug, comments

Is there way to use a resize icon in the bottom right corner to expand the height of textarea, or this functionality not work on Galaxy S5? I tried with dragging, click and hold, double and triple clicks, but noting happens.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: That's not really about Stack Exchange, which only give a standard textarea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Android (Galaxy S5) I just longpress-n-drag the corner you pointed (the functionality is similar with any textareas defined as resizeble).

> [image]

<sup>Your iPhone screenshot doesn't look Applish though, more like the stock browser from it the stock Android 4.4 with TouchWiz...</sup>

Comment: +1 for guessing the correct device.